# throw error on invalid updates of nested mongo db object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

for nested object,

```
rating: {
      average: {
        type: Number,
        default: 4.5,
        min: [1, 'Rating must be above 1.0'],
        max: [5, 'Rating must be below 5.0'],
        set: (val) => Math.round(val * 10) / 10, // 4.666666, 46.6666, 47, 4.7
      },
      count: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      },
    }
```

if I hit the 'update' request as

```
{
    "rating": 6
}
```

it is modifying my object.

So w.r.t **'Update'** query:

1. how can I keep a check in the schema itself for invalid nested object updates
2. also not update the keys which are not provided

Comment: How do you "hit the 'update' request"?  What did you expect to happen vs what did happen

Answer (score 0):

This is a design issue. The types of the same field should be kept consistent. If changes are needed, please use new fields to avoid excessive maintenance costs